# Confusion in Union all Operator

Tags: plsql, oracle12c, union-all

I am using Oracle SQL Developer

I am combining two output of two queries using union all operator.

I am giving simple example because I cant share whole query (Working
 for Bank)

```
select * from tb1 where rownum between &range1 and &range2
Union all

select * from tb2 where rownum between &range1 and &range2
```

first query gives all credit transaction, second query gives Sum of Debit.
but I found wrong debit amount using above syntax.

when i use below syntax it gives correct Output

```
select * from tb1 where row_num between &range1 and &range2
Union all------------bug

select * from tb2 where row_num between &range3 and &range4
```

I just placed comment after union all, and this giving correct output.
I just cant understand how this can be possible?

Comment: `comments` has nothing to do with query output. Trust me. Also, if i see your both query i can see the range is changing for both the queries. Are you passing the correct range for both of your queries ?

Comment: I am giving same ranges for 1st and 2nd query  . range1 =5001 ,range2=10000. range3=5001, range3=10000

Comment: Give a try by simply hard coding the range rather than passing it.

Comment: as per your suggestions i have applied hard code ranges ,but found same issue

Comment: A simplified example is great, but for this I think we are going to need a working demo so we can reproduce the issue ourselves. I agree with @XING, it doesn't seem possible that a comment where you have it in your example could make any difference, so there must be something different in your actual query.